# Active admin custom filter with active record relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

Here is my problem:

I have three models:

Taxons

```
class Taxon < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, :uniq => true
```

Categories

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :taxons,       :uniq => true
  has_many :products
```

And Products

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
```

In Active Admin, I have to add a custom filter for searching products by taxons.

If you have an idea, how todo it, I would be most gratefull for any help.

P.S. I also have a nested set in taxons, if that's important

Comment: hemnn, sorry I ask you, are sure understand many to many? and using `has_and_belongs_to_many`? I confuse with your relation by I read in your code.

Comment: me too, can you please add the join table to make that clear

Comment: I have a "categories_taxons" join table with "category_id" and "taxon_id" fields.  It's also not all the relations i have, That ones just to display a relations between these three models